# Minimum and maximum determinant selection.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, discrete-optimization

Given a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m \gt n$.

Suppose, I get to choose any $n$ unique rows from $X$ to form a new matrix $Y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. And it's guranteed all the $Y_i$ has positive determinant by applying absolute value.

What's the best way to pick $Y_{max}$ and $Y_{min}$ that has maximum determinant and minimum determinant?

A straight forward way maybe scan all ${m \choose n}$ different $Y_i$, but not necessary efficient if $m \gt \gt n$.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: determinants aren't defined for non-square matrices. (But this doesn't matter for the rest of your question.)

Comment: sorry about the error, thanks for pointing out, just updated

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee that all the $Y_i$ have positive determinant. Swapping two rows in a matrix negates the determinant. I guess you can modify the question to ask for the minimum and maximum absolute determinant, but I don't know the motivation/context behind your question.

Comment: hmm, yeah sorry i forget about the absolute value, the motivation is actually for determining the vertices with minimum and maximum solid angle in a zonotope construction.